# Python: decoding a string that consists of both unicode code points and unicode text

Tags: python, unicode

Parsing some HTML content I got the following string:

```
АБВ\u003d\"res
```

The common advice on handling it appears to be to decode using unicode_escape. However, this results in the following:

```
ÐÐÐ="res
```

The escaped characters get correctly decoded, but cyrillic letters for some reason get mangled. Other than using regexes to extract everything that looks like a unicode string, decoding only them using unicode_escape and then putting everything into a new string, which other methods exist to decode strings with unicode code points in Python?

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] that shows this behaviour, including a `repr()` output of the original value you decoded.

Comment: Presumably this is Python 2.7 and the input is a *byte string*? So the repr could be `'\xd0\x90\xd0\x91\xd0\x92\\u003d\\"res'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This _is_ a minimal example. repr() output is 
    `Ð\x90Ð\x91Ð\x92="res`
And no, this is Python 3.

Comment: No it is not. There is no code. I had to guess as to how to reproduce your output.

Comment: And a proper MCVE would have shown us you are using Python 3.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I thought MVCE only referred to the input and output, and also it didn't occur to me that Python version might matter in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unicode_escape` treats the input as *Latin-1 encoded*; any bytes that do not represent a Python string literal escape sequence are decoded mapping bytes directly to Unicode codepoints. You gave it UTF-8 bytes, so the cyrillic characters are represented with 2 bytes each where decoded to two Latin-1 characters each, one of which is U+00D0 `Ð`, the other unprintable:

```
>>> print repr('АБВ\\u003d\\"res')
'\xd0\x90\xd0\x91\xd0\x92\\u003d\\"res'
>>> print repr('АБВ\\u003d\\"res'.decode('latin1'))
u'\xd0\x90\xd0\x91\xd0\x92\\u003d\\"res'
>>> print 'АБВ\\u003d\\"res'.decode('latin1')
ÐÐÐ\u003d\"res
```

This kind of mis-decoding is called a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), and can be repaired by re-encoding to Latin-1, then decoding from the correct codec (UTF-8 in your case):

```
>>> print 'АБВ\u003d\\"res'.decode('unicode_escape')
ÐÐÐ="res
>>> print 'АБВ\u003d\\"res'.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
АБВ="res
```

Note that this will *fail* if the `\uhhhh` escape sequences encode codepoints outside of the Latin-1 range (U+0000-U+00FF).

The Python 3 equivalent of the above uses [`codecs.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode):

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode('АБВ\\u003d\\"res', 'unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'АБВ="res'
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex really is the easiest solution (Python 3):

```
text = 'АБВ\\u003d\\"re'
re.sub(r'(?i)(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\u([0-9a-f]{4})', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), text)
```

This works fine with any 4-nibble Unicode escape, and can be pretty easily extended to other escapes.

For Python 2, make all strings `u''` strings, and use `unichr`.

Comment: OK, noted that this is for Python 3. (Using unicode strings and `unichr` makes it work for Python 2)

Comment: The OP is almost certainly using Python 2 however; they have a UTF-8 bytestring (which is why they get the Mojibake output they posted in their question).